# I am new in git. I started installing through waching online video but it showing error. fatal: pathspec 'index.html' did not match any files

Tags: git

I have just started learing GIT. Follow their tutorial.
Now at the very beginning I got stuck with this error:

[image]

Comment: Try `git status` to learn the pathnames of the untracked files.

Comment: Don't paste screenshot, copy the lines. Link to the tutorial that you follow. Show the steps you did before.

Answer (score 1):

You are in ~ ($HOME), which is not a good place for a `git init`: you should not make a Git repository in your `$HOME` (which can include all kind of files, including `~/.ssh` sensitive ones).

A `git init myrepo` in `HOME` would make `~/myrepo` a repository.
Then, in `myrepo` folder, you can copy/create new files and add them.

Or a `git clone https://url/to/remote/myrepo` would similarly create a myrepo folder.

In both instances, you do not simply `git init` in `~`.